# Playing with Exception in subclass

Tags: c#, exception, subclass

My questions are:

1. How to play with Exceptions inside connect() method (propagation)?
2. Should I use **this** keyword (this.Open()... or Open() is enough)?

Base class given:

```
class BaseClient
{
    public BaseClient(string host, string port);
    public void Open();
    public bool Authenticate();
    public void Close();
}
```

To create an instance of the object and establish connection:

```
BaseClient client = new BaseClient(host, port);

try
{
    client.Open();
    bool flag = !client.Authenticate();
    if (flag)
    {
        throw new SNException();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    bool flag = client.State == State.Opened;
    if (flag)
    {
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

Now I wish to subclass BaseClient and enclose Open() and Authenticate() methods in one method connect().

```
class ChildClient : BaseClient
{
    public ChildClient(string host, string port) : base(string host, string port);
    public void connect();
    public void disconnect();
}
```

where:

```
public void connect()
{
    this.Open();
    ...
    this.Authenticate();
    ...
}

public void disconnect()
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: for the second question `Open()` should be enough.For the exception part, if `Connect()` is calling `Authenticate()` then it's part of callers job to propagate the exception if not authorized.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

> 1.How to play with Exceptions inside connect() method (propagation)?

If you don't have any way to handle the error within `connect`, such as catching it and returning a boolean `false` silently, don't do anything - leave your code as it is.

> 2. Should I use **this** keyword (this.Open()... or Open() is enough)?

You don't need to use **this** if the method identifiers you use are not in confilict with other defined methods (`using NamespaceWithAuthenticate;` for example would break that). It is implicit to use *this* to resolve the method.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. How to play with Exceptions inside connect() method (propagation)?

Enumeration type

```
public enum State {OK, WARNING, ERROR, OPENED, CLOSED};
```

Initializes a new instance of the Exception class.

```
internal class SNException : Exception
{
    private State _state;

    public State GetState
    {
        get { return this._state; }
    }

    public SNException()
    {
    }

    public SNException(State state)
    {
        this._state = state;
    }

    public SNException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }

    public SNException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException)
    {
    }

    protected SNException(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
    }
}
```

BaseClient class

```
class BaseClient
{   
    private string host = "";
    private string port = "";

    public BaseClient(string host, string port)
    {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void Open()
    {
        throw new SNException(State.CLOSED);
    }

    public bool Authenticate()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void Close()
    {}
}
```

Class ChildClient inhertis on the base BaseClient class

```
class ChildClient : BaseClient
{
    public ChildClient(string host, string port) : base(host, port)
    {
    }

    public bool connect()
    {
        this.Open();

        return this.Authenticate();
    }

    public void disconnect()
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Calling object

```
ChildClient childClietn = new ChildClient("host", "port");
try
{
    bool result = childClietn.connect();
}
catch (SNException ex)
{
    var st = ex.GetState;
}
finally
{
    childClietn.disconnect();
}
```

### 2. Should I use this keyword (this.Open()... or Open() is enough)?

The **this** keyword refers to the current instance of the class and is also used as a modifier of the first parameter of an extension method.

```
    public BaseClient(string host, string port)
    {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }
```

If this parameter in the method or constructor has the same name as the variable in the object, then you need to explicitly indicate where to assign a value.